# How to import a python file in another blender python file

Tags: python, blender

I am using blender python for a project. I have two files say one.py and two.py
I need to import one.py inside two.py. I have tried

```
from . import one
from one import *
```

but both did'nt work. What is the right way to import other files inside blender python script

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Do you get errors? What do the errors say?

Comment: That is standard python, doing it in blender should not make any difference. Are the two scripts in the current directory? are they inside a dir that is listed in `sys.path`?